# perl DBI execute statement for LOAD DATA INFILE

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

I am relatively new to perl and this forum. I am trying to use perl DBI for mySql LOAD DATA INFILE statement to upload a csv file to a mySQL database. However, the execute statement returns an undef value. However if i use a SELECT or DESC statement, it works fine. I suspect that the single quotes and braces in the query is causing the error but don't know how to debug.

```
   #!/usr/bin/perl -w
   use strict;
   use warnings;
   use File::Basename;

    use DBI;
    use DBD::mySQL;
    my $data_path="D:\\NickD\\Project\\StockData\\"; 
    my $db = "TestMMDB";
    my $user = "user";
    my $pass ="pass";
    my $host = "localhost";
    my $query ="";
    my @row;   

    my @files = glob("$data_path*.csv");
    DBI->trace(1);


    my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:mysql:$db:$host",$user,$pass);

    foreach my $file(@files){
        my $filename = basename($file);
        my ($db_table,$date) = split("_",$filename);       

        $query = q{LOAD DATA INFILE ? INTO TABLE ? FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' (Date,Symbol,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume)};      

    my $sqlQuery = $dbh->prepare($query);
    my $rv = $sqlQuery->execute($file,$db.".".$db_table) or die "Oops!: Can't execute the query :".$sqlQuery->errstr;
    while (@row = $sqlQuery->fetchrow_array()) {
        print "@row\n";
        } 
    }
    my $rc = $dbh->disconnect();
    exit(0);
```

All help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The `?` placeholder is only allowed in places where an expression is permitted in a SQL query. You can't use it for table, column, or file names.

Comment: Cross-posted at [PerlMonks](http://perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=1058110).